# what does the CakePHP test suite do? What is the purpose of it?

Tags: php, cakephp

Why must I use the test suite? I have never used any  SimpleTest Unit Test, or any testsuit. If write a testsuit won't it take a lot of time?

I don't understand the purpose of it. Please explain the benefits.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Writing tests for your code allows you to automate the testing process, so any future amends or additions that cause errors can be picked up easily. It also usually means that you've thought about and planned your code before you start.

Have a read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing